# Raycast from one object to side of the other object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ai (the red circle) which should shoot at my player (the blue circle).

Currently i'm using a normal Raycast:

```
Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
```

which gives me the purple Line.

Now, when there is a corner (like on the image), it doesn't hit the player, but it could if it would shoot a bit more to the side.

I've seen a solution for this by adding an angle to that raycast, but this doesn't work for me, because the angle is different if the player is near or far away from the ai.

What i need is:

That the ai shoots a raycast from itself to the side (left &  right) of the player, but i don't know how to do that.

[image]

Comment: even if you did one recast on each side of the player, you'd still have a problem if for example the shooter sees the target BETWEEN two walls...

Comment: the game i'm working on is pretty simple, there is no place in the entire map where the player could be seen between two walls. if i could find a solution for just hitting the player on the left/right side, it would be enough for my game.

Comment: ok i tried to give you a hint on how to do it in my answer bellow, is it helping?

Answer (score 0):

You can find good answer [HERE](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1239291/finding-point-of-mesh-visible-by-another-game-obje.html).

Or maybe use [Sphere Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) and use `Contact Point` and shot at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Your player certainly has some kind of radius, no?
Just using the distance between the player and the shooting AI, the player's radius and some nice trigonometry, you should be able to generate two rays to test both if the shooting AI sees the player's "right side", as well as his "left side".

```
Vector3 direction = player.transform.position - shootingAI.transform.position;
float distance = direction.magnitude;
float playerRadius = player.radius;// this is a variable you need to set
float angleToRotate = Mathf.Atan(radius/distance); // trigonometry: tan(angle)=oppositeSideLength/adjacentSideLength

Vector3 rayDirection1 = Quaternion.Euler(0f, -angleToRotate, 0f) * direction;
Vector3 rayDirection2 = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angleToRotate, 0f) * direction;
```

Using these two rays as directions you should be testing for the "right side", and the "left side"